# how to inactivate an app in itunes?

Tags: ios, itunes

Probably I don't see all options when registering an App in Itunes, because I actually submited my app for reviewing.

If once an app is online. Is it easy to inactivate and reactivate an app in itunes. Or does it go again through a check from apple ?
And when possible to inactivate, does it immadiatelly inactivate ?
In Androids Google Play this can take up to a halve day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to make the app inactive and active.

You have to follow through these steps

1. Login to itunesconnect
2. Choose your app in My Apps section
3. Under Appstore tab choose "Pricing and Availability"
4. Under Availability section click edit will open a popup listing the territories
5. Uncheck all the territories and click Done

These steps will make your app inactive in all the appstores. This will get effect within 24 hours

You can Select the territories again to make it available again. It will not go through the app store process again.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I will accept. May I ask you something additionally ? How long does it take to approve an app from Apple ? My status is "waiting for approvement" since 2 days. The explanation for this status is, that the review has not started yet.

Comment: There is no actual date for that but i would say an average of 7 days. This site provides an average value for app approval http://appreviewtimes.com/ which displays the average as 7 days.

Comment: May I ask you again something. Its the last one :-) If an app is approved and a new version is apploaded, does it take also again 7 days in average ?

Comment: I think it also sticks to the same time i mentioned. But you have to consider the word average. In realtime one of my apps uploaded with new version got approved in 2 days and the same apps next version approved in 9 days.

Comment: Ok, I see :-) So we have to be very sure, that everything is running fine from start .Thanks for helping out and kind regards.

Comment: Anyways Good Luck for your app :]